# I have a website running on Magento where my account feature does not work on the mobile version of the website

Tags: magento2, layout, css, html

I have a website running on Magento where my account feature does not work on the mobile version of the website. I want it to look like the second picture when I click on the account button. enter image description here enter image description here

I tried moving around elements using command, but I could not figure it out.
[image][image]

Comment: can you please share a link of your website?